# IBM Watson Assistant respons delay from bot

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am playing around with IBM Watson Assistant (digital chatbot) and I want to implement a delay so that the chatbot waits 1-3 seconds with sending the respons.

Is there any way I can do this? I saw on earlier pots that it was not supported yet.

Mille

Comment: You could do that in the app / middleware.

Comment: @data_henrik so I can't direclty implement it in the dialog?

thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

I can only suggest calling a cloud function that delays for 3 seconds before returning, in your dialog code. A delay is not supported in the dialog itself.

Comment: Note that cloud function calls need to terminate within 5 seconds.